# How can I find the specific user that has access to a shared mailbox?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that read a textfile with many shared mailboxes. I need to remove who has FullAccess, but I need to save who has access to another file for backup, if something should go wrong.

I'm trying to find a specific user that has access to a shared mailbox or at least I don't want the 3 users that's not marked in the attachment.

I just have this code for now:

```
Get-MailboxPermission -Id pffinanceadministration.wyong@company.com | ? {$_.AccessRights -match "FullAccess" -and !$_.IsInherited}
```

and as you can see in the attachment I get a little bit more than I need.

I'm trying to get what's marked in the attachment.

How can it be done so I only get what's marked?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by _"I need to save who has access to another file for backup"_? For starters you could eliminate all `NT AUTHORITY` users in the Where-Object clause.

Comment: What I mean is, that if users are contacting me and inform that they don't have access to the mailbox anymore, I need to know which group the user was member of for adding the same group again. I'm trying to clean up our shared mailboxe.